# Oracle SQL : Querying data using Table Function passing rows from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table function that takes parameters in and pipelined the row back.

```
get_cnt_info(param1, param2, param3)
```

I need to pass the data from a physical table as the parameter to that function.

```
select name, address, agefrom tblPerson;
```

I need to do it in SQL, I have tried something like below, but is not working.

```
select d.*, (select cnt 
               from table(get_cnt_info(d.name, d.address, d.age))) 
 cnt from tblPerson d;
```

Any idea on how I can do it? Please help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which Oracle version?

Comment: it is Oracle 10g

Answer (score 0):

Does the pipelined function run successfully when executed as, for example,
SELECT get_cnt_info(param1, param2, param3) FROM DUAL ?

What error messages do you get ?